# How to connect Jenkins with Postgres DB

Tags: postgresql, jenkins, user-roles

I have a requirement to create the users in PostgreSQL DB using Jenkins pipeline. It will be greatly appreciated if someone could share reliable links. Currently I am stuck on how to start.

I am a newbie in Jenkins.

Answer (score 0):

To connect Jenkins with a PSQL Database, you would first need to setup [psql driver plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/database-postgresql/) in jenkins. You can add the plugin & manage the configuration from the `Jenkins Setup`.

Once you are done with this, the best way to interact with the db would be to write the commands you need to execute in a shell script file, like `$HOME/db_scripts/add_user.sh` which you can execute from the jenkins directly.

Hope this answers your question!